# Text view inside the Linear layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

i have created three linear layouts of equal weights. Inside one of the linear layouts i have 6 text views. I have initialized the text view in my activity. But i'm not able to view this text view. I don't know where i'm going wrong. Please help me.

This is my XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/lay"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#FFFFFF">
<TextView android:id="@+id/num1" 
 android:layout_width="0dip" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="left"
 android:textColor="#000000" 
 android:textSize="10dip"
 android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/date1" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/cus1" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/service1" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/job1" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/des1" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="#FFFFFF" >
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="@string/followup"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
 android:lines="3" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my activity

```
public class Detail extends Activity{
String value1 , value2;
Cursor c, c1;
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.detail);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);
        TextView  tv1 =(TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.num1);
        TextView  tv2 =(TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.date1);
        TextView  tv3 =(TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.cus1);
        TextView  tv4 =(TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.service1);
        TextView  tv5 =(TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.job1);
        TextView  tv6 =(TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.des1);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null)
        {
        value1 = extras.getString("keyName");
        value2 = extras.getString("keyTime");
        }
        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }

        myDbHelper.setSearch(value1);
        c = myDbHelper.getDetail();
        if(c.getCount()!=0){
            c.moveToFirst();

            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                tv1.setText("Ticket No:" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("taskID")));
                tv2.setText("Date:" + value2 + "/" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time")) );
                tv3.setText("Customer Name:" + value1);
                tv4.setText("Description:" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("taskDetail")));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        c.close();
        }


        myDbHelper.setSearch(value1);
        c1 = myDbHelper.getService();
        if(c1.getCount()!=0){
            c1.moveToFirst();

            while (!c1.isAfterLast()) {
                tv5.setText("Service Type:" + c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("description")));
                tv6.setText(value1);
                c1.moveToNext();
            }
        c1.close();
        }

        myDbHelper.close();}}
```

I want a layout like this, [image: Layout]
First two text in the same line one at the right and another at the left corner, the other four vertically down. How to achieve this?

Comment: as you are using wrap content for your TextView and not using any text in xml, they won't be visible. So if you want to see them, initialize the text in xml with some random text and change to the desired text dynamically in your code

Comment: I initialized the text with some random text. But then i'm able to view only the first two text views in the same line with weight=1.

Comment: May be thats because you gave weight = 1 for only 1st 2 TextViews

Comment: How you want to display textView ? horizontal or vertical ?

Comment: I am having same issue and updating textview text in activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `layout_width` attribute `TextView`s to be `0dip`, but only two of the six of them have a `layout_weight` attribute. The other four will have a zero width.

Either:

- Set your four lowest `TextView`s to have a width > `0dip`...
- ...Or, add the `layout_width` attribute to the remaining four `TextView`s, just as you did with the first two.

**Edit as per comments:**

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is just a basic draft so you get an idea of what layouts belong where. Remember to set your layout weights, widths, heights, IDs, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: I tried to update my code like how you suggested. but i'm not able to achieve the layout i want. i want the first two texts in the same line one at the right end and another at the left end, the other four should be one after another vertically down. How to achieve this?

Comment: You should have one `vertical` `LinearLayout`. This should contain two `LinearLayout`s: a `horizontal` one and a `vertical` one. In the `horizontal` one should be your first two `TextView`s, and the other four should be in the `vertical` one. I'll update my answer with a simple draft solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/num1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000" 
                android:textSize="10dip"
                android:text="test"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/date1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dip" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="test"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/cus1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dip"
                android:text="test" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/service1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dip" 
                android:text="test"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/job1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dip" 
                android:text="test"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/des1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dip" 
                android:text="test"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/followup"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is put a Table Layout or 3 LinearLayout inside the weight=1.

3 rows with 2 columns and width fixed

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cus1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/service1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/des1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each textviews inside the linearlayouts are invisible unless you set the text on each textviews

Comment: i have set the text dynamically in my activity using its respective id.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix you problem. Here is what i have fixed I don't know what exactly you need. I think you want to show your text views in same linear layout with equal width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/lay"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#FFFFFF">
<TextView android:id="@+id/num1" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="left"
 android:textColor="#000000" 
 android:textSize="10sp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="rgfgfd"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/date1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10sp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="sdfsdfsdf"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/cus1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/service1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/job1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/des1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="10dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="#FFFFFF" >
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="followup"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
 android:lines="3" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

for horizontal textviews:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cus1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/service1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/des1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/followup"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

For vertical textViews

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cus1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/service1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/des1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="ryhgfderuh"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/followup"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See this image. I have solve your issue:

[image]

Follow this XML code to make it possible:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lay" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/num1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="first" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/date1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="second" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/cus1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="third" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="10dip" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/service1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="fourth" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="10dip" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/job1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="fifth" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="10dip" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/des1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="sixth" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="followup" android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help you.

Enjoy Coading. . . .

:)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you intend to achieve a layout like this:

[image]

I have used this layout to achieve the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Top Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:text="text 1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView 
                android:background="#00ff00"
                android:text="text 2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:background="#ffff22"
            android:text="text 3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:text="text 4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:background="#00ffff"
            android:text="text 5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:background="#ff3322"
            android:text="text 6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Middle Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#0ff3ff"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can edit the `android:background` and `android:text` tags to suit your purpose.